# ORM: Select from table A only if id exists in table B

Tags: mysql, sql, orm, sqlalchemy

Ineed a query/method in SQLAlchemy which selects from table A only if the id exists in table B.

I think it's expressed like this in SQL

```
SELECT id, number FROM a WHERE EXISTS (SELECT id from B);
```

If there are alternative queries that are just as fast or faster those are good too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please state what exactly you try to achieve?
I am not quite sure what your `SQL` query is supposed to do, and in the `SELECT id from B` which table is `id` column from?

In any case, if it is from `B`, then below should do it:

```
from sqlalchemy import exists, select
q = select([A.id, A.number]).where(exists(select([B.id])))
```

*But again, I cannot make sense out of this query.*

Comment: I think that does it. On the query: I have one superset C and two subsets A and B which refer to some ids in C, not all of them. I needed a query that would consistently select ids that existed in both A and B, but I figured it out using an alternative approach. Thanks.

Comment: I guess the simple inner `join` does the job most efficiently

Comment: hi van i want to clarify one thing i want the same thing as this i never done this before but let me ask you this for example i have 3 table; `t1, t2, t3,` i have inner join on them like `t1.id inner join t2.id inner join t3.id`  my where would be `where t1.id = 1 and t2.id = 1 and t3.id = 3` problem is if the only does on exist in any table no result is return. what should be done in this problem

Comment: i hope you can shed light on this problem thank you in advance

Comment: additional info i still want to select or fire the query even if it does not exist on other tables meaning i will only select from table where the id exists

Comment: the first comment i have has wrong query this is the correct query `t1 inner join t2 on t1.id = t2.id inner join t3 on t2.id = t3.id where t1.id = 1 and t2.id = 1 and t3.id = 1`

Comment: @HogRider: what does your query have to do with `exists`?

Comment: i have 3 tables namely t1 t2 t3 i want to query the 3 tables for a certain entry.using id as parameter.i am using inner join now. i have given my select in the comment above.my problem is for example the id is not existing in t3.the query will not fire.how would i make it in a way that if it does not exist in t3 they table that it will query will be t1 t2 and will return an entry. it is possible that the id will not exist in t2 and will exist in t3 al possible not exist in t1 but in t2 and t3 exist

Comment: I am sorry, but I really find it difficult to understand your explanation. Could you make a *real* (somewhat less abstract) example?

Comment: this is a query representation of the query `Select * from t1 
inner join t2 on t1.id = t2.id 
inner join t3 on t2.id = t3.id 
where t1.id = 1 and t2.id = 1 and t3.id = 1` what if the id does not exist in t3 if will not return any right?i still want to return the result from t1 and t2 since the id exist in t1 and t2

Comment: if you wanted to support *not exists in table X* only for two tables (t2 and t3), then you could do `select * from t1 LETF OUTER join t2 on ... LEFT OUTER join t3 ...` to support this. But if you need all three cases, you probably will need to have separate queries and use `UNION` to merge them together

Comment: i see, so the only option is to use union thank you for the idea i will search for union right away.i was hoping to just use one select query for this but since it is not possible then i will go with union thank you again